# HTML - Why are Links and Images draggable by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable

I am developing a project and the default drag-drop behaviour is not desirable for me. So instead of writing `draggable="false"` onto all of my `<a>` and `<img>` tags I am using jQuery to set there `draggable` attributes on ready.

```
$('a, img').attr('draggable', 'false');
```

But I also have content that is added dynamically, so again I am calling the function that sets dragging to false when that content is loaded.

My question is, why is this behaviour enabled in the first place? Shouldn't it be the the developers choice to enable dragging or not? - I have been force to go to some lengths to disable dragging, perhaps there is a better solution. Does it contradict the Semantics of HTML to enable behaviour by default? i.e A plain `<a href="#">` doesn't describe it as being draggable, but it is.

Comment: because standard browser behavior is to allow dragging/dropping links/images to create shortcuts or open that link in the target 'drop' window.

Comment: you are always going to have a hard time changing how browsers work. If you are fighting to change default behavour you might be going down the wrong road. why is it causing issues? "default drag-drop behaviour is not desirable for me" but it is completely expected by users

Comment: I suspect this is an invented problem that doesn't actually need to be solved.  Why is it so critical that this website override standard browser behavior?  This seems similar to developers who want to disable right-click, and will likely meet with the same user frustrations.

Comment: @David: As an example, if I were to create a FTP browser then I would expect that I could be able to drag and drop files around the file system or between different file systems. Similarly I might choose to replace the context menu(right-click) to give the option to show file(s) properties. To me, these kinds of interaction cases seem normal/expected when emulating Desktop GUI on the web.

Comment: @doveyg: Providing contextual dragging/dropping indeed is useful.  Blanketly denying any and all dragging/dropping by the host system is not.

Comment: @David We are creating a database application were users input data into text fields.
During user testing, we found that some users where dragging links and images into input fields, some of our `<a>` had Javascript functions as the href (I know, wasn't up to me) - So we wanted to disable drag-and-drap to prevent uses submitting dragging and submitting links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links and Pictures are draggable from default so that you can drag them to a search-bar/browser-tag to only show the image or specific link.

If you want to turn off this default behaviour you can use this css-code:
e.g for an img-tag

```
img
{
-webkit-user-select: none;
-moz-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```

I haven't used it for links, but it should work too

Comment: After reading on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) I see this is nonstandard and not recommended for production use, it also doesn't seem to work on my Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/f6yu6y7h/ - So I guess the way I did it works okay